# Excel VBA workbooks.open ReadOnly:=False

Tags: excel, vba

I have this statement in Excel VBA:

```vb
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileName, ReadOnly:=False
```

The workbook that I am trying to open is on our SharePoint site.

When it opens, it's still in read-only mode, even though I have `ReadOnly:=False`.

Is there another parameter I need to include on this statement?

Comment: Is the file marked as read only?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening in read only initially and switching the file access mode to *xlReadWrite*

```
Dim wb1 as Workbook

Workbooks.Open Filename:=cell.Value, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=0
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook 'set wb2 variable to the opened workbook
wb1.ChangeFileAccess (xlReadWrite)
```

If the file is password protected initially, it will need to be **.SaveAs** using that password afterwords. Otherwise normally saving will leave it in an unprotected state where anyone will have access to change it.

```
wb1.SaveAs Filename:=cell.Value, WriteResPassword:="*******"
```

Comment: I was encouraged when I read about the xlReadWrite option.  Unfortunately, it gives me this error: Method 'ChangeFileAccess' of object  '_Workbook' failed.  I even checked the ReadOnly property ahead of time and confirmed it is "True" before I started.  Can't help but think our Sharepoint site has some type of security built in where a read-only property cannot be changed programmatically? Just a wild guess here.